# Need to Sync postgresql DB to remote

Tags: postgresql

I have two PostgreSQL standalone servers *A* and *B*. From server *A* I need to sync only one database and table to server *B*. How should I proceed?

Comment: You can use logical replication using pglogical: https://2ndquadrant.com/en/resources/pglogical/

Comment: Can you provide more context for "sync" here? Postgres has a lot of solutions for this. If you want to do some kind of daily backup workflow, perhaps you could use `pg_dump` or `COPY`. It's also possible for two Postgres servers to connect to each other live with `dblink`, which lets you access remote data without having to clone it.

Answer (score 8):

As answered before, you have loads of different ways of doing this. Here are a few:

- External logical replication: projects like [Slony](http://www.slony.info/), [Londiste](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/SkyTools), [Bucardo](https://bucardo.org/wiki/Bucardo) can replicate the needed objects through triggers;
- Extensions like [pglogical](https://2ndquadrant.com/en/resources/pglogical/);
- In-core logical replication which is available since Postgres 10
- Foreign Data Wrappers: you could use [postgres_fdw](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/postgres-fdw.html) to make your table readable from a remote server. This means connecting to the other table, not replicating it.
- Backup and restore: you could cron a pg_dump and restore of your table from server A to B.
- Physical Replication: you could replicate the whole A cluster on cluster B using streaming replication. This could give you a nice disaster recovery solution. On the B server, you could then issue one of the solutions above to a second instance on the server B.
- and probably several other ways :-).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sync a single database or table, then you can use  [**Bucardo**](https://bucardo.org/). This will help you to replicate a single table, single database, etc.